# NPM "Failed to remove some directories" when running NPM install

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am trying to run npm install which does not work properly. When I run the command it gets all the npm packages. However when it starts with the cleanup it gives me the following error:

```
3242 timing build:link Completed in 222ms
3243 info run deasync@0.1.28 install node_modules/deasync node ./build.js
3244 info run yorkie@2.0.0 install node_modules/yorkie node bin/install.js
3245 info run yorkie@2.0.0 install { code: 0, signal: null }
3246 timing build:run:install:node_modules/yorkie Completed in 235ms
3247 info run deasync@0.1.28 install { code: 1, signal: null }
3248 warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
3248 warn cleanup   [
3248 warn cleanup     'D:\\Repos\\XX\\frontend\\legacy\\node_modules\\@storybook\\addon-essentials',
3248 warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\Repos\XX\frontend\legacy\node_modules\@storybook\addon-essentials\node_modules\@storybook\addon-docs\dist\modern'] {
3248 warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
3248 warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
3248 warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
3248 warn cleanup       path: 'D:\\Repos\\XX\\frontend\\legacy\\node_modules\\@storybook\\addon-essentials\\node_modules\\@storybook\\addon-docs\\dist\\modern'
3248 warn cleanup     }
3248 warn cleanup   ],
3248 warn cleanup   [
3248 warn cleanup     'D:\\Repos\\XX\\frontend\\legacy\\node_modules\\@storybook',
3248 warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\Repos\XX\frontend\legacy\node_modules\@storybook\addon-essentials'] {
3248 warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
3248 warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
3248 warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
3248 warn cleanup       path: 'D:\\Repos\\XX\\frontend\\legacy\\node_modules\\@storybook\\addon-essentials'
3248 warn cleanup     }
3248 warn cleanup   ]
3248 warn cleanup ]
```

To me it looks like it does not have the permissions to remove some folders, however I do not know how to fix this. I made sure nothing was running when running npm install and even tried running npm install in administrator mode.

What could be the cause of this?

I am on node v20.8.0

Comment: Maybe at some point the permissions got messed up. You can try removing your `node_modules` folder with `rm -rf` (or in case you are using Windows CMD some equivalent), and run `npm install` again.

Comment: @JSONDerulo Hey thanks for your comment! I just tried it but it seems to give me the same issue unfortunately

Comment: Any resolution on this? Same thing is happening to me, but in CI on a clean virtual machine. Baffling!

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case:

```bash
npm cache clear --force
```